# chmod without modding other user perms

Tags: bash, chmod

I want to chmod a file but I want to do it so it doesn't effect the other "user"/"groups"

e.g. giving the root 0

```
before 741
chmod 0** [filename]
after 041
```

or give the group a 7

```
before 741
chmod *7* [filename]
after 771
```

anyway to do this?

Comment: Learn to use chmod symbolic mode [Using CHMOD in symbolic mode for more fine grained control](http://crashmag.net/using-chmod-in-symbolic-mode-for-more-fine-grained-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the symbolic representation, which has `+` and `-`:

```
chmod u-rwx         # remove rwx permissions from user
```

or

```
chmod g+rwx         # add rwx permissions to group
```